# AdMob is not showing in my list view

Tags: listview, admob

My ad in the design tab is not showing at all, I don't know what I am missing,
And when I put it before my listview, it's showing on top right and pushing my buttons to the right, I don't know what can be the reason of this,

Please help me,
Thanks

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chap1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/chap1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chap2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/chap2"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chap3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/chap3"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I have changed the android:layout_height="match_parent" to  android:layout_height="wrap_content" and I have added weight as suggested in similar posts but this didn't solve my problem, I have finished my app and now I am only waiting for this to publish my app :/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `scrollview` and `adview`  by `fragmentlayout`